# How to use for loop to print cards?

Tags: python, playing-cards

I have all 52 cards set up, and i try to print all 52 cards by using `for loop`.
I don't know how to set my `for loop` at this point.

```
def define_cards(n):
    rank_string = ("ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king")
    suit_string = ("clubs","diamonds","hearts","spades")
    cards = []
    for suit in range(4):
        for rank in range(13):
            card_string = rank_string[rank] + " of " + suit_string[suit]
            cards.append(card_string)

print "The cards are:"
for i in range(52):              #how to make this for loop work??
    print i, card_string[i]
```

I want to print like this

```
The crads are:
0 ace of clubs
1 two of clubs
2 three of clubs
...
49 jack of spades
50 queen of spades
51 king of spades
```

Comment: this is a one-liner: `cards = enumerate(rank+' of '+suit for suit in suits for rank in ranks)` -- see answer for more details

Comment: Please mark your homework with the [homework] tag, also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `define_cards` has to return the list. Add `return cards` at its end.

Then you have to actually call/execute this function.

Then you can access individual cards in this list:

```
cards = define_cards()
for i, card in enumerate(cards):
    print i, card
```

However, if you are searching for a "more pythonic" solution, try this:

```
import itertools as it

rank_string = ("ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king")
suit_string = ("clubs","diamonds","hearts","spades")

print 'The cards are:'
for i, card in enumerate(it.product(rank_string, suit_string)):
    print i, '{0[1]} of {0[0]}'.format(card)
```

Comment: i had try your first answers, is work, but why only print once??

Comment: @phhnk - where did you put the `return cards`?  At the end of the function, just below `for suit in range(4):`, so with an indent of 4 spaces?

Comment: i was put below `cards.append(card_string)`

Comment: @phhnk - yes, below `cards.append(card_string)` , but indented eight spaces left from it.

Answer (score 2):

Look at just this

```
    cards.append(card_string)

print "The cards are:"
for i in range(52):              #how to make this for loop work??
    print i, card_string[i]
```

Why print `card_string[i]`?

What's wrong with `cards[i]`?

Comment: @phhnk: What does "won't work" mean?  I can't guess.  I'm not blessed with Extra Sensory Perception.

Comment: @phhnk - it won't work until you execute your `define_cards` function.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a iterator :

```
def define_cards():
    rank_string = ("ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king")
    suit_string = ("clubs","diamonds","hearts","spades")
    for suit in suit_string:      # you can obtain the items of the iterate list directly, no need of rank access
        for rank in rank_string:
            card_string = rank + " of " + suit
            yield card_string

print "The cards are:"
cards_iterator = define_cards()
for i, card in enumerate(cards_iterator):   # use the iterator power ;)
    print i, card
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ranks = ("ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king")
suits = ("clubs","diamonds","hearts","spades")
```

Answer is an elegant one-liner:

```
cards = [rank+' of '+suit for suit in suits for rank in ranks]

for i,card in enumerate(cards):
    print i, card
```

Result:

```
0 ace of clubs
1 two of clubs
...
50 queen of spades
51 king of spades
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def define_cards():
    rank_string = ("ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king")
    suit_string = ("clubs","diamonds","hearts","spades")
    cards = []
    n = 0
    for suit in suit_string:
        for rank in rank_string:
            print '%s %s of %s' % (n,rank,suit)
            n+=1

define_cards()
```